# Trying to Print Data from Get Request via Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, material-ui, axios

I'm trying to print off SQL data from a get request using axios. I'm using express server-side, and my front end is React. Within my react component, I have a function that has the axios GET call, and then I call that said function within the render. I can get the data fine. My issue is actually printing the data to the table. Here is my code so far:

```
  getTableData(){
      axios.get("/api")
      .then(function (response){
        return(
          Object.keys(response).map( (row, index) => (
              <TableRow key={index} selected="false">
                <TableRowColumn>Test</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>Test</TableRowColumn>
              </TableRow>
          ))
        )
      })
      .catch(function (error){
          console.log(error);
      })
  }
```

This is the function I use to do the API call, as well as try to print the table. I call it within the render function as {this.getTabledata()}.

Here is the the get request within my server.js:

```
app.get('/api', function (req, res){
    sql.connect(config, err =>{
        new sql.Request().query('select * from Counselling', (err, result) =>{
            var table = new Object();
            result["recordset"].map( (row, index) => (
                table[row["StudentName"]] = row["StudentNumber"]
            ));
            res.send(table);
            sql.close();
        });
    });
```

Is there something I'm missing? Do I have to use a specific mapping function for the rows?

Comment: If you are calling it from the render each time you have a re-render you make a database call. It can be costly if your component changes often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all don't make the `api call` directly from `render` method, do that either in `componentDidMount` lifecycle method or on any specific `event`. Store the response in `state` variable because api call will be a asynchronous call, it will not `return` the ui elements.

Use this to fetch the data from server:

```
componentDidMount(){
    axios.get("/api")
        .then( (response) => {
            this.setState({response: response})
        })
        .catch( (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
}
```

Use this method, it will `return` the Table rows once you get the response from server, because when we do `setState`, `React render` the component again.

```
getTableData(){

    if(!this.state.response) return null;  //added this line

    return Object.keys(this.state.response).map( (row, index) => (
         <TableRow key={index} selected="false">
             <TableRowColumn>Test</TableRowColumn>
             <TableRowColumn>Test</TableRowColumn>
         </TableRow>
    ))     
}
```

Comment: Hey, when I getInitialState, what should I set the response state variable to? Right now, I have it as response: null, but this creates an error, and thus stops the rendering process.

Comment: check the updated answer, set the `value` of `response` to `null` in `getInitialState` and put the check inside `getTableData` method.

Comment: Hey, forgot to reply, but this solved my issue. Thank you very much!

Comment: glad, it helped you :)